# Wie soll ich eine Bewerbung per E-Mail anfangen?

Tags: formality, salutation, letter

Also ich will mich bei einem Träger für ein Bfd bewerben, aber weiß nicht mit welcher Anrede ich anfangen soll. Es scheint nur ein Mann die Bewerbungen zu empfangen, mit ihm habe ich auch schon telefoniert, weiß seinen Namen aber nicht. Deswegen klingt "Sehr geehrte Damen und Herren," komisch und "Sehr geehrter Herr ------" kann ich ohne den Namen auch nicht schreiben.

Comment: Abgesehen davon, dass das mit der deutschen Sprache per se herzlich wenig zu tun hat und daher meines Erachtens nach fehl am Platze ist, würde ich zu der Variante "Sehr geehrte Damen und Herren" greifen, da das im Allgemeinen freundlich klingt und nicht negativ behaftet ist. Die Alternative wäre natürlich, dort anzurufen und sich nochmals nach dem Namen des Herrn zu erkundigen.

Comment: Bfd=Befund, Bindfaden, Brieffreund, Busenfreund? @Sprottenwels: Nun, ehemals hieß die Seite "German language and usage", weil es auch Konventionen gibt, die von Land zu Land oder Sprachraum zu SR unterschiedlich sind.

Comment: @userunknown Es sei auch drum. Prinzipiell stört es ja keinen, wenn eine solche Anfrage hier auftaucht. Bfd dürfte übrigens der Bundesfreiwilligendienst sein.

Comment: Wer oder was ist »Bfd«?

Comment: Ich bin dafür, diese Frage zu schließen, weil sie nichts mit der deutschen Sprache zu tun hat. Dieselbe Fragestellung kann in jeder beliebigen Sprache auftreten, und kann auch in jeder beliebigen Sprache gleich beantwortet werden.

Comment: Ich bin dafür, die Frage offenzulassen, denn sie beschäftigt sich mit einer Konvention der deutschen Sprache – wobei sich das Deutsche durchaus von anderen Sprachen unterscheidet. Die »optimale« Lösung wäre natürlich, wenn OP den Namen seines Gegenübers herausgefunden (oder gleich beim Telefonat erfragt) hätte.

Comment: Also ich finde man sollte eine Frage erst mal gar nicht mit "also" anfangen. Und wenn es dann noch eine Frage nach einem höflichen Briefanfang ist: Aaaalso... [geht Kopfschüttelnd ab]

Answer (score 1):

Bewerbungen werden normalerweise mit "Sehr geehrte Damen und Herren" eingeleitet, da man sich üblicherweise nicht sicher sein kann, wer die Bewerbung initial und später in die Finger bekommt. Dies gilt sowohl für schriftlich und postalisch eingereichte Bewerbungen, wie auch für eMail-Bewerbungen.

Comment: Wobei ich aber durchaus schon den Tipp gelesen habe, die zuständige Ansprechperson herauszufinden, an die die Bewerbung gehen wird, und diese Person im Anschreiben zu grüßen. Das soll dann zeigen, dass man sich eingehend mit den Strukturen der Firma, an der man sich bewirbt, auseinandergesetzt hat und blablakeks.

Comment: Karl Valentin hat eine ganze Szene darüber, wie einer versucht, einen Beschwerdebrief zu schreiben, und nicht weiß, welche Anrede er verwenden soll. "Geehrter" will er nicht schreiben, denn er möchte nicht die Unwahrheit sagen. Am Ende schreiber er nur: **"Sehr Herr!"**